How to reference highlighter.js within lit element?
How do we use highlight.js inside a lit element web component if we are importing highlight.js in a index.html file.
So for example in the head element of index.html we may have this:
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.9.0/styles/default.min.css"
    />
    <script type="module">
      import hljs from 'https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.9.0/es/highlight.min.js';
      //  and it's easy to individually load & register additional languages
      import go from 'https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.9.0/es/languages/go.min.js';
      hljs.registerLanguage('go', go);
    </script>

Which makes hljs available, but if we try to use it inside the connectedCallback function of the web component like this:
this._code = hljs.highlightAuto(this.innerHTML);


The linting creates the error:
Cannot find name 'hljs'.(2304)
any

So how should we go about referencing hljs within the web component?

Note that the highlightElement function takes an element, not a string (so just pass it this). As for how to get your linter to not complain: tell it that hljs is a global/external (the linting config docs cover how to do that)
